# R CMD INSTALL --build but without actual installation

Tags: r

Is it possible to build a binary package without trying to install it into the libraries directory -- ie. just have R produce package_R_(arch).tar.gz?
`R CMD INSTALL --build package` works, but it overwrites the installed package of the same name, and would fail complaining about the lock file if that package is currently loaded.

Comment: Why not use `R CMD build`?

Comment: @shadow: because that builds the source tarball. `R CMD INSTALL --build` creates binaries.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried `R CMD build --binary`, but it has apparently been deprecated and no longer works :(

Comment: `R CMD INSTALL --build --library=/tmp $PKG && rm -rf tmp/$PKG`